What does "include step output in history"-setting control in SQL Server Agent for TSQL steps?
When you create a TSQL job step, there's an advanced setting called: "Include step output in history", but I don't understand what this setting controls:

A sample job script:
DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'SampleJob', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=2, 
        @notify_level_netsend=2, 
        @notify_level_page=2, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_name=N'SampleJob', @step_name=N'Include step in history', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=N'print ''Include step in history''', 
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=4

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_name=N'SampleJob', @server_name = null

Regardless if it's checked or not, I can't get the step output to show up in job history:

Note that I have a CMD command which does output into history.
So, it seems this setting doesn't control anything for TSQL job steps, or does this output somewhere else?
Note that I don't have any problem with "Log to table" / "Append output" settings, they control sysjobstepslogs output.
Note #2, all step outputs are being added to sysjobhistory, regardless if this flag is set or not, so that doesn't seem to be it either.

haha good question I've been seeing that checkbox for 20 years and wondering what it means

Might this not be better asked on DBA?

I couldn't find any difference in behavior, other than sp_help_job shows that the flags for that step are set to 20 or 12 ((include results in history)) (you can see flags = 20 or 12 in sysjobsteps, but the text is the giveaway). I'm curious what exactly is meant by "output" and "results" here. At first I thought maybe if the step returned data to the ether (some SELECT OR OUTPUT), it might log those results. Still looking around for something...

Oh, i think i see it now. It controls if resultset output of a query is saved into sysjobhistory for a step or not.

I'm not seeing that, though. For me, rows in sysjobhistory and sysjobstepslogs look the same (except when they're just not present in the latter) regardless of the combination of settings: config, results. No evidence of any resultset anywhere, just the rowcount in the stepslogs table (regardless of that checkbox). Perhaps that was the intended and even the observed behavior at some point, but it no longer works that way?

Strange @AaronBertrand, i'm running sql server 2016, but not sure if that has bearing. This is the final script i'm running https://dbfiddle.uk/oh0VxnKp

I can see that step 8 adds some kind of resultset to sysjobhistory and step 9 and 10 also added some stuff to sysjobstepslogs

Ah, I didn't try with append checked, though that seems like it should be unrelated (especially to what happens in sysjobhistory). And I could only get the results into sysjobhistory if the SELECT is the first statement in the job step - seems like behavior similar to the describe_for_first_resultset modules. Anyway, the label of the checkbox and the behavior are both very far from intuitive. (I'm on 2022, this server is 16.0.4105.2.)

Yeah, you're right, it actually seems to choose PRINTs over resultsets regardless of order of the commands when logging to jobhistory. Maybe there's a method to it's madness. Wonder if i can get microsoft to document these quirks

After some collaboration and experimentation, we've determined that the checkbox will show resultset output in sysjobhistory - as long as no other output-affecting statements, like PRINT or RAISERROR, are executed in the same step.
If you check the box "Include step output in history":

The following step:
 SELECT foo = 'step 1';

Will lead to the following row in sysjobhistory (cr/lf added by me):
 Executed as user: <whoever>. 

 foo
 ------
 step 1

 (1 rows(s) affected).  

 The step succeeded.


The following step:
 SELECT foo = 'step 2';
 PRINT 'this is the second step';

Results in the following row in sysjobhistory, without the resultset output:
 Executed as user: <whoever>. 

 this is the second step [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0).  

 The step succeeded.



If you want the step output to reliably end up somewhere, regardless of the rest of the job step (or any future changes), also choose the "Log to table" option - in which case the output will be captured in sysjobstepslogs even when it is suppressed from sysjobhistory. Those same two steps would produce the following in the log column. Step 1 (without print):
Job 'testing' : Step 1, 'step 1 - without print' : 
Began Executing <whenever>

foo   
------
step 1

(1 rows(s) affected)

Step 2 (with print):
Job 'testing' : Step 2, 'step 2 - with print' : 
Began Executing <whenever>

foo   
------
step 2

(1 rows(s) affected)

this is the second step [SQLSTATE 01000]

Just be wary of how much output you might have, because this could blow up msdb if you aren't careful.
